# Content loss from JSON file when fetching it from server

Tags: ios, json

I have an API and I want to fetch some data from it as a JSON file using POST request.

**The problem is :**

data on the server look like this:

```
{
  "countryID":"30"
  "countryName":"Syria" 
},
```

data I received from the http request -before parsing- is :

```
{
  "countryID":"30"
  "countryName":"" 
},
```

*there is no value for every text field like countryName .*

the http request is :

```
‫NSString * post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lang=%@",@"English"];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setTimeoutInterval:60];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection* connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];‬
```

the last thing I want to mention that the received JSON file contains a header before the JSON data like this :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

**My Question**

Is there any mistake in the HTTP request causing this problem? or it's server side problem?

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that the server is a PHP server and the url format of the request is as look like :

```
 https://website.com/api/data.php
```

Comment: Is there actually a missing comma between the properties?

Comment: Are you sure the server is sending you the country name? Double check with a proxy like Charles Proxy, I found that tool invaluable in debugging client/server issues.

Comment: By the looks of it, a full request is being returned.  It isn't malformed, so it is highly likely it is a server-side issue

Comment: As @Tim said the JSON file on the server is well formed I test it on JSON viewer and it worked fine. 
And the http request returned the whole file without missing any field but the value of text fields like names are received empty.

Comment: Please answer Mike Brant's question.

Comment: @MikeBrant no there is no missed commas, the file is well formatted. I tested it using http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ and If there was any problem in the JSON file it would discovered .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the response you're getting has two problems: it doesn't have the content you expect, and its format is off - it sounds like the HTTP body of the response has both HTML and JSON in it.

The first problem is some sort of application-level issue; either you're not sending the right query, or the server isn't interpreting it correctly, or it has some sort of other bug. So it could be on either side.

The second problem, though, is probably a server-side issue; it's not returning a coherent response. That said, you might be able to prod the server to do the right thing by telling it explicitly that you want a JSON response:

```
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
```

Depends on the server, though. Good luck!

Comment: Regarding the second issue it's solved in server side recently and the HTML header removed from the returned file , and it's now pure JSON.
So the HTTP request now received only JSON file , I've tried to change the values of the request as you suggest but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any json errors in the debugger, like the `Garbage At End` error? Are you using NSJSONSerialization to handle the JSON on the iOS end? What happens if you use the `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` option of NSJSONSerialization?

I'd have posted this as a comment but I'm underprivileged. :(

Comment: the problem occurred before parsing step,and after parsing the file parsed well without any error except that the content of text fields is empty because it was received like that from the server, so I don't think it's a parsing problem.